# recursively go through list to calculate the percentage change between two items at every n elements

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to create a function that calculates the difference between every nth element in a list. ie. I want to calculate the difference between i[5] and i[0] then i[11] and i[6] etc.

I created this function recursively such that it calculates the % change. Then, the value gets appended to a list (growthList). Finally, I remove the first 5 elements of the list (input list) and repeat the process.

I get the expected output. However, the del function alters the original list. I was wondering if there is a better way to remove the first 5 elements of the list without altering the original list. See code below:

```
growthList = []

def growth(lst, n):
    '''calculates the % of periods (n) this item is growing in'''
if len(lst) < n:
    return growthList
else:
    y = lst[n] / lst[0] - 1
    growthList.append(y)
    del lst[0:n]
    newList = lst
    growthCalc(newList, n)


growth(l, 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing:

```
del lst[0:n]
newList = lst
```

To:

```
newList = lst[n:]
```

Comment: That did the trick. Much simpler and cleaner! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned about altering the original list, just make a copy of the list and then delete the first five items:

```
newList = lst.copy()
del newList[:n]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this led to an error TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len() but the above answer worked

Comment: Sorry my bad. Updated now! Forgot to add the "()" after the copy function

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to do something similar, I found a better way to do this without recursion. See below:

```
def growth(lst, stepVal):
    growthList = []
    x = lst[::stepVal]

    for previous, current in zip(x, x[1:]):
        y = ((current / previous) - 1) * 100
        growthList.append(y)

    return growthList
```

The idea is to create a single list using the zip function skipping every stepVal number of times and perform the calculation (y) on that single list.